# Expo for ReactNative installed but where?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I installed Expo for React Native to create an app dev environment on my Mac terminal. But now I can't run eas or expo and have my shell find the executables.

I tried

`npm install -g eas-cli`

and it successfully installed. Then I tried adding npm to my .bashrc

`export PATH=$PATH:~/.npm-global/bin`

But when I type on the command line

`eas`

or

`expo`

I get

`zsh: command not found:`

I want to know where the packages are but can't find them with finder or from shell